# Showing page not found in Django

Tags: python, django

My url.py is like :

```
url(r'^admin/employee/employee_master/isEmpPresent/(\d{4})/$', 'employee.views.isEmpPresent' ),
```

My views.py is :

```
def isEmpPresent(request,emp_id):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return HttpResponse(emp_id)
```

My url is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/employee/employee_master/isEmpPresent/333/
```

But I am getting the error "Page not Found". What mistake i am making? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The convention in Python, especially in Django, is PEP-8 for naming of classes, methods, and functions. For example, the isEmpPresent() view function would be is_emp_present().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\d{4})` --> this regex means exactly 4 values but you have only 3 values. Replace `(\d{4})` with `(\d{3})`

Comment: Perfect @sachitad , so please clear me  `(\d{4})` means the digit count should be 4 and for `(\d{3})`  digit count should be 3 right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If the numbers in your URL is exactly of three digits, use that. But if you want it be only integer with no matter how many digits use `\d+` instead. `\d+` means only numbers.